# Can't add extra argument to Python(Django) function call

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to serialize data with a serialiser and also I have a file for saving but I can't path the extra varible with file to my serializer

```
issue_dict = request.data.get('issue')
file = request.data.get('file')
```

**This is working fine:**

```
 serializer = WriteIssueSerializer(data=issue_dict, context=self.get_serializer_context())
```

**This is what I'd like to get, but it says "got an unexpected keyword argument 'file'" :**

```
 serializer = WriteIssueSerializer(data=issue_dict, file=file, context=self.get_serializer_context())
```

I understand that inside the serializer I should define variable "file",
so look at this serializer:

```
class WriteIssueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    notes = IssueNoteSerializer(many=True)

    def create(self, val):
        issue_dict = val.get('issue')
        # issue_dict['assigned_to'] = issue_dict['assigned_to']['id']
        # issue_dict['reported_by'] = issue_dict['reported_by']['id']

        assigned_to_id = issue_dict.pop('assigned_to').id
        reported_by_id = issue_dict.pop('reported_by').id
        notes_info = issue_dict.pop('notes')
        # print(validated_data.pop('file'))
        issue = Issue.objects.create(assigned_to_id=assigned_to_id, reported_by_id=reported_by_id, **issue_dict)
        for note_info in notes_info:
            note = IssueNote.objects.create(**note_info)
            note.issue = issue
```

It's obvious that changing from 
`def create(self, val):` to `def create(self, val, file):` will fix my error, but **not**, the error is still the same

Answer (score 1):

```
serializer = WriteIssueSerializer(data=issue_dict, file=file, context=self.get_serializer_context())
```

This calls the *constructor* of WriteIssueSerializer (`__init__()`), not `.create()`. So you have to create the extra argument in there, or call `.create()`.